# WPF Custom Shaped Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a custom shaped listBox in WPF which I will use to display some stuff. I need it to look something like a cloud shape (see attachment). What is the simplest way to achieve this (preffably in Blend). Many thanks.

[image: Cloud Shape]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be to just have a cloud image (preferably SVG) and on top of that drop a list box with no border on it.

**EDIT:** Here is a styled / templated way to do the whole thing (you'll need to tweak to make it look exactly how you want):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="362" Width="574">

    <Window.Resources>

        <!--Control colors.-->
        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


        <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
        <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

        <!--Border colors-->
        <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
        <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

        <!--Control-specific resources.-->
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="1,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.4" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.6" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="1" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBox}"
       TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth"
          Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight"
          Value="95" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">


                        <!-- This is the meat of the template -->    
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="/WpfApplication2;component/Cloud.png" />

                            <StackPanel Margin="2" Background="Transparent"
                                    IsItemsHost="True" />

                        </Grid>    

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                   Value="false">

                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                   Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                    Value="false" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="Azure">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

            <ListBox 

                x:Name="ListBox1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                HorizontalAlignment="left" 
                Height="Auto" 
                Width="Auto" 
                Background="Red" >


            </ListBox>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I referenced this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242.aspx) to come up with this (as I don't have blend installed).

Comment: Hmm problem with that is that the content of my listBox is dynamic so I would like to autoSize the listBox depending on the contents.

Comment: You can still do that... As long as you get the listbox part expanding dynamically in the same container that houses the image of the cloud, it should stretch the cloud just fine (I suggested an SVG image for the cloud so that it would scale well during just that scenario).

Comment: -1 This is a small portion of the end goal and does not in any way address the templating component.

Comment: @Aaron - I was just trying to get the basic concept across. I've since added a fully templated control that demonstrates the concept.